Need to replace sliding glass door, but what is the metal on the frame?
I have no idea what this metal thing is and, thus, how to proceed since all the sliding glass door installation tutorials, instructions, and videos I've seen have wood framing instead of whatever this metal thing is.
details: I need to replace my exterior sliding glass door but while inspecting it I realized that there's this metal thing running all around the perimeter of the opening and the door itself isn't even screwed into it. It looks more like the door was just friction fit since none of the screw holes were used to secure the door frame, which kinda tracks with how the previous homeowners would "fix" something.
I'm hoping someone knows what this metal is and, how this may affect replacing the sliding glass door myself. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I just can't afford to hire any of the contractors or window companies that have given me estimates.
FYI, the pic is from the top of the opening, but the plaster (or whatever it is called) that is crumbling away on the sides of the opening also have this metal strip underneath them.
Thanks for your help!

It's drywall corner bead. Not part of the door or framing. Likely the door is attached to the wood/steel framing underneath the drywall and the drywall is finished to the edge of the door frame. This bit provides a nice square corner finish and adds considerable durability to what would otherwise be a fragile edge.
Since you don't really provide any context, we can't really help you with more complete instructions.

I need to replace the door because it's not closing, there's no weather stripping and it's from the 80s so it's extremely energy deficient. The walls in this room and in particular around the opening, are almost impossible to drill into and I'm just trying to learn all I can about what may be going on with it before I take the door out, which in and of itself is interesting since, as I mentioned, I can't see how it's actually mounted to anything as there are no screws. I'll go study up on corner beads but the metal is around the entire opening, so a good 5", not just on the corners.

Hard to tell with such a zoomed in picture. I think this metal piece serves the same purpose though. Perhaps you could include more pictures of the frame so we have more context. It looks like the spot showing some rust might be a fastener, but I can't tell what exactly it may be holding.
